# JS not being added when using addJS in Prestashop 1.7.1.1

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am developing a custom module in Prestashop 1.7.1.1

The module includes specific CSS and JS.

I am trying to add it by using:

```
<?php
class mymodule_searchbar extends Module
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->name = 'mymodule_searchbar';
                $this->displayName = 'Mymodule Search Bar';
                $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
                $this->version = '1.0';
                $this->author = 'Mymodule';
                $this->bootstrap = true;
                parent::__construct();
        }

        public function hookDisplayHome()
        {
                $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'views/css/bootstrap-select.css', 'all');
                $this->context->controller->addJS(($this>_path).'views/js/bootstrap-select.js');

                return $this->display(__FILE__, 'displayHome.tpl');
        }

        public function install() {
                parent::install();
                !$this->registerHook('displayHome');
                return true;
        }

}
```

I can see via firefox debug that `bootstrap-select.css` is being loaded but `bootstrap-select.js` is not. I have triple checked names, paths, and file permissions.

Why is the JS not being added? Is there anything else I can do for further debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the CSS and JS files in the header, also you should add your tpl file in the views, try with this code below and relocate your `displayHome.tpl` in case it’s not in the specified path.

```
<?php

class mymodule_searchbar extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodule_searchbar';
        $this->displayName = 'Mymodule Search Bar';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'Mymodule';
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('displayHeader') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayHome');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    public function hookDisplayHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/bootstrap-select.css');
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/bootstrap-select.js');
    }

    public function hookDisplayHome()
    {
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/displayHome.tpl');
    }
}
```

PD. Uninstall your current module and then install again this to add the hook of `displayHeader`, and as good practice, clear your cache.

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo `($this>_path)` instead of `($this->_path)`.

I also moved the CSS and JS to DisplayHeader as recommended.